# how I can extract images from html code and then validate if are stored in my web server

Tags: php, html, regex, image

I've been working on a post editor, I want to generate thumbnails from all images inserted on the html code, so, before to do that I want to get all basic image attributes

example:

```
$mydomain = 'mysite.com';
$htmlcode = <<<EOD
<p>sample text</p>
<img src='/path/to/my/image.ext' width='120' height='90'  />
<hr />
<img src='html://www.mysite.com/some/ther/path/image.ext' /> <!-- no attributes -->
<hr />
<p>blah blah <img src="http://www.notmyserver.com/path/lorem-ipsum.ext" widht='120' height='90' /></p>
EOD;


function get_all_image_attributes($htmlcode){    
// some code... 
return $images; // array with image src (required), width (if has), heigth (if has)...
}

// then validate (I really need this part)    
$images   = get_all_image_attributes($htmlcode);

function verify($images,$mydomain){
// code...
return $valid_images;
}
```

A valid image would be (.jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png)

src="/path/image.ext"

src="http://www.mysite.com/path/image.ext"

src="http://www.mysite.com/some/path/image.ext"

src="http://mysite.com/some/path/image.ext"

src="www.mysite.com/path/image.ext"

ps.

The part to generate thumbnails is already done,  don't worry :)

### updated

```
//I have done the following
$html = str_get_html($html);
$images = $html->find('img');
foreach ($images as $image){
 $filename = getfilename($image);
// I would like validate the file if is located in other path,
// or if it contains 'http://[www.]mysite.com/'
 if(file_exists(PUBLICPATH.'post_images/'.$filename))
  valid_imgs[] =  BASEURL.'post_images/'.$filename;
}

function getfilename($full_filename){
    $filename = substr( strrchr($full_filename , "/") ,1);  
    if(!$filename)
      $filename = $full_filename;   
    $filename = preg_replace("/^[.]*/","",$filename);
    return $filename;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function GetImagesFromHTML($strHTMLContent) {
    $HTMLDOM = new DOMDocument();
    $HTMLDOM->loadHTML($strHTMLContent);
    $arrContentImages = array();

    foreach ($HTMLDOM->getElementsByTagName("img") as $objImage) {
        $arrContentImages[] = $objImage->getAttribute("src");

    }

    return (!empty($arrContentImages)) ? $arrContentImages : false;

}
```

I've seen a few suggestions about Converting the DOM object into SimpleXML so you can use Xpath, I tried that and while it worked it still required further processing of the result nested object which just adds more work for the server if all you care about is getting the value of the src for all the images in a block of HTML, so I wrote the above function to do the job, doesn't require conversion to XPath, just uses the PHP5 built in DOM parser and gives you back an array like:

```
Array(
   [0] => value1.jpg
   [1] => value2.jpg
   [2] => value3.jpg
   [3] => res/upload.jpg
   [4] => value4.jpg
   [5] => value5.jpg
   [6] => value6.jpg
)
```

Total exection time for the function 0.00071001052856445 seconds

Answer (score 3):

Use an HTML parser. With [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), you can do something along the lines of this:

```
$html = str_get_html($htmlcode);
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    verify_image($element->src);
}
```

Comment: you could also use a regex, or use simpleXML with XPATH.

Comment: And simpleXML won't tolerate invalid html. you would have to run it through html tidy or similar first.

Comment: general rules aren't always true, regex is fine for this

Answer (score 0):

something like this would probably be good:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
open(F, 'tmp.txt');
while(<F>) { 
   while (m/img[^>]* src="([^"]+)"/g) { 
      my $imgurl = $1;
      verify_image($imgurl);
   }
}
```

Comment: While this should work for many cases, it would not verify any image that doesn't have the src immediately after <img - so if there was something like <img id="x" src="x.gif"> it wouldn't be checked.